# Error Android com.google.android.gms.r$styleable error

Tags: android

I'm getting an com.google.android.gms.r$styleable error

In Manifest file code is below and my package is com.ex.map.

Min sdk version 8 and max sdk version 21.

```
<permission
      android:name="com.ex.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.ex.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>   

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="1" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ProximityActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.ex.map.proximity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
            </intent-filter>

    </activity>       

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my key here"/>        

</application>
```

MainActivity is my first launcher activity. Unfortunately my app is stopped and displays the above error message. I also included the google play services jar to lib folder manually.

In log cat error message:

```
 04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Process: com.ex.map, PID: 1164
 04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2158)
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-20 01:46:23.461: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
```

Comment: where is the error message. Post log trace

Comment: Above is my log cat error message

Comment: Have you added a google play services jar file?

Comment: I did it. Manually i added to my app's libs folder.

Comment: You need to check that jar file in `Order and Export Menu` Option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line of code in manifest:-

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="1" />
```

put this line of code inside  tag where you have declared activities and map key:-

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'). while adding the above statement.

Comment: Please put the updated google play service lib jar to your project and clean the project